# How to merge two types of for comprehension in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, for-comprehension

I have seen for being used different ways in Scala, to take some value out of a wrapper like Option or on list or other collections. If I have to pull a `List[Int]` out of an `Option` and then iterate on it, can this be done in one for block?

eg.

```
val l: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1,2,3,4)) 
l: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
 for{
  li <- l       // li taken out from Option wrapper
  number <- li  // numbers pulled from li
} yield number*2 
cmd7.scala:3: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Option[?]
number <- li
       ^
```

If I understand correctly it wants each entry to be an `Option`. Is there some way to achieve this effect without two for loops?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some way to achieve this effect without two for loops?

You can do this by calling `toList` on the `Option[List[Int]]`, turning it into a `List[List[Int]]` which the `for` comprehension will `flatMap` over:

```
for {
     | o <- l.toList
     | num <- o
     | } yield num * 2
res8: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

This will yield an empty list for the `None` type:

```
scala> val l: Option[List[Int]] = None
scala> for {
     | o <- l.toList
     | num <- o
     | } yield num * 2
res3: List[Int] = List()
```

You can also use `Option[T].getOrElse` with an empty `List[T]` as fallback if the option is empty:

```
scala> for {
     | o <- l.getOrElse(List())
     | } yield o * 2
res13: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Personally, I like the explicit `map` call:

```
scala> l.map(_.map(_ * 2))
res7: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(2, 4, 6, 8))
```

Answer (score 2):

For comprehensions expand to `flatMap`s, `map`s and lazy version of `filter`. `flatMap` for `Option` does not accept function `A => List[A]`. In general you can use only one type of monad in for comprehension.

Obvious solution here are monad transformers. If you have two monads, one in another, it allows you to access the values inside the deeper monad by creating another monad that combines behavior of two.

Note that this works for any two monads, not just `Option` and `List`.

Using scalaz:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val list: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4))

(for {
  number <- ListT(list)
} yield number * 2).run

res0: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(2, 4, 6, 8))
```

You need to call `run` to unwrap the value from transformer.

you can then use more than one list like this:

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3).some
val ys = List(0, 2).some

(for {
  x <- ListT(xs)
  y <- ListT(ys)
} yield x * y).run

res0: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6))
```

If any `Option` would be `None` the result would be `None` as well

```
(for {
  x <- ListT(xs)
  y <- ListT(ys)
  z <- ListT(none[List[Int]])
} yield x * y).run

res0: Option[List[Int]] = None
```